# Is a "supercritical charge" in graphene similar to Hawking Radiation?

Tags: gravity, atomic-physics, hawking-radiation, graphene

These papers describe a phenomenon referred to as "atomic collapse" and "supercritical charge" in graphene: [Wang et al.](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/340/6133/734.abstract), [Pereira et al.](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v99/i16/e166802)

"Atomic collapse" appears when you have a large enough Coulomb potential in a system described by the Dirac Equation. In the case of graphene, a localized state is embedded in the continuum below the Dirac Point, causing an electron to fall into the state, leaving behind a hole.

I was wondering whether something similar could happen for gravity.  I know gravity is due to the curvature of spacetime rather than a Coulomb potential, but the phenomenon described by the papers cited above seem reminiscent of Hawking Radiation.  Is "atomic collapse" the electromagnetic analog of Hawking Radiation?